Is the $\ell$-adic cohomology ring of a cubic threefold a complete invariant?
The only interesting $\ell$-adic cohomology of a smooth cubic threefold $X$ is $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(2))$, which is isomorphic as a $\mathrm{Gal}_k$-module to $H^1(JX,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(1))^{\vee}$ when the intermediate Jacobian $JX$ exists. Moreover, the cup product $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(2)) \otimes H^3(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(2)) \to \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(1)$ corresponds to $cl_1(\theta) \in H^2(JX,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(1))$ under this isomorphism, where $\theta$ is the canonical theta divisor on $JX$. It is known that the pair $(JX,\theta)$ determines $X$ up to isomorphism for arbitrary fields $k$ of characteristic not $2$.
So my question is, does the $\textrm{Gal}_k$-module $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(2))$ with its cup product determine the cubic threefold $X$ up to isomorphism? That is, if two such structures for cubic threefolds $X,X'$ are isomorphic, then are $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic?
What other classes of varieties are distinguished by their $\ell$-adic cohomology rings?

Certainly not if $k$ is algebraically closed...

@abx Can it at least detect different twists of a cubic threefold?

For these kind of problems related to the Tate Conjecture, you usually need to assume that $k$ is finitely generated, for example a number field.
